# Repl.it: Package operation failed on repl.it freeCodeCamp

Tags: python

i'm trying to get certificate on freeCodeCamp by making project on repl.it . Everything goes well until this happened. I don't know what happen, i have search it on google but i still didn't understand. I appreciate for your help

```
Python 3.8.2 (default, Feb 26 2020, 02:56:10)
>

Repl.it: Updating package configuration

--> python3 -m poetry lock

[RuntimeError]
The Poetry configuration is invalid:
  - 'description' is a required property

exit status 1


Repl.it: Package operation failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `Add description="" between [tool.poetry] and [tool.poetry.dependencies]`

Example :

```
[tool]
[tool.poetry]
authors = ["Your Name <you@example.com>"]
description=""
name = "root"
version = "0.0.0"
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
pandas = "*"
python = "^3.7"
seaborn = "*"
```